# how to scale an image on python-opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

When i tried to scale the photo in python it gives me this error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

My code:

```
cv.SetImageROI(image, (pt1[0], pt1[1],pt2[0]-pt1[0], int((pt2[1] - pt1[1]) * 0.6)))
```

Comment: You might be mixing tabs and spaces when indenting code, so the code looks like it's all indented properly, but Python doesn't think so. (This can happen if you have an editor that inserts tab (\t) character when you press tab key, but you sometimes press the space bar to indent code as well; or when you have an editor that inserts spaces when you press tab key and then you switch to an editor that inserts tab (\t) character when you press tab key).

Comment: btw, please try to use cv2, not the deprecated cv api

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your indentation in python.

In python code must be aligned together when in the same scope.